# How to: fencing in 2 nodes cluster with iLO 4?

Tags: centos, hp, pacemaker, ilo, fencing

I have configure a 2 node (master/slave) cluster on `HP GL360p` servers with `iLO 4`. OS is centos 7 and I am using `pcs` with `pacemaker` and `corosync`. 
I want to implement fencing but I can't find any documents about how to get started with it.  My requirement are simple: if one of the node becomes unavailable the other reboots it through its `iLO` interface. And I cant buy additional hardware for this test setup at this stage.

Comment: They're DL360p's by the way, not GL - also I'm not sure your understanding of fencing is right I'm sorry, you need to add more information - but essentially if you want one machine to control the power of another via iLO there are lots of options - read the instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ilo4 you can use fence_ipmilan:

[Man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/fence_ipmilan)

[An example](http://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/_example.html)

Comment: I have read this before and from what I can see the device mentioned in config is used to control multiple servers, I have no idea what kind of device thats supposed to be, all my searches have turned up to be about traditional iLO interface. Anyway as I mentioned I am not looking for any additional/external device, but to somehow manager the onboard iLO device.

Comment: "IPMI device" is the generic term for ILO.  In the specific example, it's referring to an ILO module in a blade chassis servicing multiple blades.  But it could also refer to the builtin ILO on a standalone server such as yours. You might also investigate 'fence_ilo4_ssh' - IMHO, it's a little simpler to understand until you get used to ILO.

Comment: @bakasan here an example used to control a single server using fence_ipmilan: pcs stonith create stonith-<pacemaker_node1> fence_ipmilan ipaddr=<ilo_ip> login=<ilo_user> passwd=<ilo_password> pcmk_host_list=<pacemaker_node1> pcmk_host_check=static-list                 fence_ipmilan use the protocol IPMI the udp port 623(check if your firewall can block it)

Comment: thanks... I had tried this before but it was not working so I assumed there was something wrong about my understanding of the setup.. anyway tried again today and managed to make it work after adding `lanplus` option.

Comment: @NoNoNo, is there way to add delay to slave stonith ? If you have any suggestion then please respond to this post https://serverfault.com/questions/906005/how-to-configure-fencing-delay-in-master-slave-cluster-with-drbd-and-pacemaker